# Short story about a female advertising executive tasked with increasing female military recruitment

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story I remember concerns a lady advertising executive in the future.  Her firm is given a non negotiable assignment by the military to help increase female recruitment.

She does this by upgrading the female uniform to make it more glamorous, and coming up with space suits that include cute keys with the astronaut's name on them so that they can be traded with fellow astronauts as a romantic gesture; actually, of course, as a safety matter, they're completely interchangeable. The military is so outraged that they threaten to draft her entire organization.

The owner of the firm, who has secretly adored her for decades, comes to the rescue by announcing that he will go public with an accusation that the military has driven her insane with worry for her colleagues.

The story was from the 50s/60s

Comment: Well, does the redesign succeed in increasing female recruitment?

Comment: "The story was from the 50s/60s." Who'd have guessed it? ;)

Comment: @Adamant And written by a man, unsurprisingly

Comment: @Adamant Ironically, the story is more relevant today than when it was written, given that different proportions are still regarded as proof of sexism, despite the [non sequitur](https://youtu.be/cQNaT52QYYA) and the [40-year-old debunking that discrimination is the primary cause](https://youtu.be/Y021WAdUlW8), with people [being fired for calling out the detriment to free speech and citing scientific studies that suggest sexism isn't the cause](https://gizmodo.com/exclusive-heres-the-full-10-page-anti-diversity-screed-1797564320). Our times are less reasonable now than in the past.

Comment: @jpmc - You may be confusing discrimination and sexism.

Comment: @Adamant Only if people who are claiming the earnings and employment gaps (the latter being what this story apparently focuses on) are due to it are.

Answer (score 24):

[A-W-F Unlimited](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57196) by Frank Herbert (1960)

Gwen Everest is a advertising executive. One fine day Gwen arrived at her firm and some military people, angry that the WOMS (Women of Space) recruitment program was an utter failure. Gwen stirs things up by redesigning the uniforms and space suits, which really makes the military angry.

Comment: Winchell Chung strikes again!